# How to register Smartmi

Tags: applications, authentication

Bought an air-purifier which can be monitored/controlled by [Smartmi app](https://www.smartmiglobal.com/pages/help-center).

To use this app one have to enter a ***Verification code***.

The app, nor the support page, say anything about what this verification code is, so it is likely one think this has something to do with google verification when searching the web.

Where to get the code?

Comment: Usually if you want to pair a device with an app and the app asks for a code this code is somehow related to the device. May be it is printed somewhere on the device or is located in the manuals or something like that.

Comment: @Robert: Thanks :), I figured it out I think. Got 8 verification codes on the e-mail I added (on same “page” as code is required) in rapid succession so perhaps some lag somewhere. Searching the web for 6-digit codes I did find i.e. https://mashable.com/article/how-to-set-up-google-authenticator and thought that was it. But not the case I believe.

Comment: Q is up for deletion by myself. (Or I might change it to fit the case and solution a bit better. Not sure if that is appropriate. Would be a ***one app Q/A***)

Answer (score 1):

When filling in the form one enters e-mail address. The app sends a verification code to that e-mail address – without any notice, or submitting the form. Not sure if one *have to* press the *“Apply verification”* button (which is after the input) for the e-mail to be sent, but it does not hurt. It also might work differently if one use a mail-account linked to the phone. (As in apply might auto-fill, but I do not know).

In my case I had to press that “button”/label for it to send a new verification that worked. I also had some lag on the first almost dozen e-mails which made me going down a rabbit hole.

After verification one have to enter WiFi password and also have Bluetooth turned on.

Would have to figure out why it need both WiFi and Bluetooth but that is another matter.

Comment: Q/A added after probing meta and looking at https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/32/360651